# Why does Tensorflow Object Detection API detect only the first class and ignores the rest?

Tags: tensorflow, object-detection-api

I ran a quick test of `ODA` on my own dataset. I noticed it only detects one class, as if there is only one class!

Here is an example where it detects the correct class:

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xme0r.jpg)

```
classes=[[ 1.  1.  2.  2.  1.  2.  1.  2.  1.  2.  2.  1.  2.  2.  2.  2.  2.  2.
   2.  2.  2.  2.  1.  2.  1.  2.  1.  1.  2.  1.  2.  1.  2.  2.  2.  2.
   1.  2.  2.  1.  2.  1.  1.  1.  2.  2.  2.  1.  1.  1.  2.  1.  1.  2.
   2.  2.  1.  1.  2.  1.  2.  2.  1.  1.  1.  2.  1.  2.  2.  1.  2.  2.
   2.  2.  1.  1.  1.  1.  2.  1.  2.  2.  1.  1.  2.  1.  2.  1.  2.  2.
   1.  1.  2.  1.  1.  2.  2.  2.  1.  2.]]
```

And here is an example where it doesn't do anything!:

[image: Example]

and these numbers that are printed below each image are the content of the `classes` variable(code given below) which I printed to see if there is any other classes recognized.

```
classes=[[ 1.  1.  2.  2.  1.  2.  1.  1.  1.  1.  2.  1.  2.  2.  2.  2.  2.  2.
   2.  2.  2.  1.  2.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  2.  2.  2.  1.  2.  1.  2.
   2.  1.  2.  1.  2.  1.  2.  2.  2.  2.  1.  2.  1.  1.  1.  1.  2.  1.
   2.  1.  2.  2.  1.  2.  1.  2.  2.  1.  2.  1.  1.  2.  1.  1.  2.  2.
   2.  1.  1.  1.  2.  2.  1.  2.  1.  2.  2.  1.  1.  1.  2.  2.  2.  2.
   1.  2.  2.  2.  2.  1.  1.  2.  1.  1.]]
```

And here is an example where it wrongfully detects a class (as you can see again it only detects class 1):

[image: Example]

```
classes=[[ 1.  2.  2.  1.  1.  2.  1.  2.  2.  2.  2.  1.  1.  1.  1.  2.  1.  1.
   2.  2.  2.  2.  2.  2.  1.  1.  2.  1.  2.  1.  1.  1.  1.  2.  1.  2.
   2.  1.  1.  2.  1.  2.  1.  1.  1.  2.  1.  1.  2.  2.  1.  2.  1.  2.
   2.  1.  1.  1.  1.  2.  1.  1.  1.  2.  2.  2.  2.  2.  2.  2.  1.  2.
   2.  2.  1.  1.  2.  2.  1.  1.  2.  2.  2.  2.  2.  1.  2.  1.  1.  1.
   2.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  2.  1.]]
```

so basically it only draws a rectangle around class 1 only! and completely ignores class 2. I'm using the code provided in the Jupyter notebook example which is as follows:

```
with detection_graph.as_default():
  with tf.Session(graph=detection_graph) as sess:
    # Definite input and output Tensors for detection_graph
    image_tensor = detection_graph.get_tensor_by_name('image_tensor:0')
    # Each box represents a part of the image where a particular object was detected.
    detection_boxes = detection_graph.get_tensor_by_name('detection_boxes:0')
    # Each score represent how level of confidence for each of the objects.
    # Score is shown on the result image, together with the class label.
    detection_scores = detection_graph.get_tensor_by_name('detection_scores:0')
    detection_classes = detection_graph.get_tensor_by_name('detection_classes:0')
    num_detections = detection_graph.get_tensor_by_name('num_detections:0')
    for image_path in TEST_IMAGE_PATHS:
      image = Image.open(image_path)
      # the array based representation of the image will be used later in order to prepare the
      # result image with boxes and labels on it.
      image_np = load_image_into_numpy_array(image)
      # Expand dimensions since the model expects images to have shape: [1, None, None, 3]
      image_np_expanded = np.expand_dims(image_np, axis=0)
      # Actual detection.
      (boxes, scores, classes, num) = sess.run(
          [detection_boxes, detection_scores, detection_classes, num_detections],
          feed_dict={image_tensor: image_np_expanded})
      # Visualization of the results of a detection.
      vis_util.visualize_boxes_and_labels_on_image_array(
          image_np,
          np.squeeze(boxes),
          np.squeeze(classes).astype(np.int32),
          np.squeeze(scores),
          category_index,
          use_normalized_coordinates=True,
          line_thickness=4,max_boxes_to_draw=50)
      #print(scores)  
      plt.figure(figsize=(image_np.shape[1] / float(96), image_np.shape[0] / float(96)))#IMAGE_SIZE
      plt.imshow(image_np)
      #matplotlib.image.imsave(os.path.basename(image_path), image_np)  
      plt.show()
      print(classes)
```

I even tried setting `min_score_thresh=0.1` yet nothing changed! I then tried `max_boxes_to_draw` as you can see, again to no avail. Code-wise anything else is identical to [this](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/object_detection/object_detection_tutorial.ipynb), except the part where it downloads the model from Internet, which I commented out and read the pre-trained model of my own.

I am new to object detection and have no idea what is causing this.

**Update**:

My labelmap looks like this :

```
item{
 id: 1
 name: 'class1'
}
item{
 id: 2
 name: 'class2'
}
```

and my dataset is composed of XML files such as below which are converted to CSV using the snippet of code I have given below. Annotation example:

```
<annotation>
  <folder>Imagenet_fldr</folder>
  <filename>resized_imgnet_17.jpg</filename>
  <path>G:\Tensorflow_section\dataset\Imagenet_fldr\resized_imgnet_17.jpg</path>
  <source>
    <database>arven</database>
  </source>
  <size>
    <width>384</width>
    <height>256</height>
    <depth>3</depth>
  </size>
  <segmented>0</segmented>
  <object>
    <name>class1</name>
    <pose>unknown</pose>
    <truncated>1</truncated>
    <difficult>0</difficult>
    <bndbox>
      <xmin>2</xmin>
      <ymin>2</ymin>
      <xmax>380</xmax>
      <ymax>252</ymax>
    </bndbox>
  </object>
</annotation>
```

and here is the snippet I used to convert XML to CSV:

```
import os
import glob
import pandas as pd
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import sys

def xml_to_csv(path,directory):
    xml_list = []
    for xml_file in glob.glob(path + '/*.xml'):
        #print(xml_file)
        tree = ET.parse(xml_file)
        root = tree.getroot()
        for member in root.findall('object'):
            value = (directory+'\\'+root.find('filename').text,
                     int(root.find('size')[0].text),
                     int(root.find('size')[1].text),
                     member[0].text,
                     int(member[4][0].text),
                     int(member[4][1].text),
                     int(member[4][2].text),
                     int(member[4][3].text)
                     )
            xml_list.append(value)
    column_name = ['filename', 'width', 'height', 'class', 'xmin', 'ymin', 'xmax', 'ymax']
    xml_df = pd.DataFrame(xml_list, columns=column_name)
    return xml_df


def main():
    for directory in os.listdir(sys.argv[1]):
        image_path = sys.argv[1]+'\\'+directory
        #print(image_path)
        xml_df = xml_to_csv(image_path,directory)
        xml_df.to_csv('{0}_labels.csv'.format(directory), index=None)
        print('Successfully converted xml to csv.')


main()
```

And finally this is how I create TFRecords:

```
"""
Usage:
  # First specify the folder containing images!
  # Create train data:
  python xgenerate_tf_record.py --images_folder G:\\Tensorflow_section\\dtset\\ --csv_input=train_labels.csv  --output_path=train.record

  # Create test data:
  python xgenerate_tf_record.py --images_folder G:\\Tensorflow_section\\dtset\\  --csv_input=test_labels.csv  --output_path=test.record
"""
from __future__ import division
from __future__ import print_function
from __future__ import absolute_import

import os
import io
import pandas as pd
import tensorflow as tf

from PIL import Image
from object_detection.utils import dataset_util
from collections import namedtuple, OrderedDict
from pathlib import Path

flags = tf.app.flags
flags.DEFINE_string('images_folder', '', 'Path to the directory containing images')
flags.DEFINE_string('csv_input', '', 'Path to the CSV input')
flags.DEFINE_string('output_path', '', 'Path to output TFRecord')
FLAGS = flags.FLAGS


# TO-DO replace this with label map
def class_text_to_int(row_label):
    if row_label == 'class2':
        return 0
    if row_label == 'class1':
        return 1    
    else:
        None


def split(df, group):
    data = namedtuple('data', ['filename', 'object'])
    gb = df.groupby(group)
    return [data(filename, gb.get_group(x)) for filename, x in zip(gb.groups.keys(), gb.groups)]


def create_tf_example(group, path):
    with tf.gfile.GFile(os.path.join(path, '{}'.format(group.filename)), 'rb') as fid:
        encoded_img = fid.read()
        #print(group, path)     
    encoded_img_io = io.BytesIO(encoded_img)
    image = Image.open(encoded_img_io)
    width, height = image.size

    filename = group.filename.encode('utf8')
    image_format = b'jpg'
    xmins = []
    xmaxs = []
    ymins = []
    ymaxs = []
    classes_text = []
    classes = []

    for index, row in group.object.iterrows():
        ext = (Path(row['filename']).suffixes)[0].split(".")[1].lower() 
        #print('format = ',ext)
        image_format = bytes(ext, encoding="utf8")
        xmins.append(row['xmin'] / width)
        xmaxs.append(row['xmax'] / width)
        ymins.append(row['ymin'] / height)
        ymaxs.append(row['ymax'] / height)
        classes_text.append(row['class'].encode('utf8'))
        classes.append(class_text_to_int(row['class']))



    tf_example = tf.train.Example(features=tf.train.Features(feature={
        'image/height': dataset_util.int64_feature(height),
        'image/width': dataset_util.int64_feature(width),
        'image/filename': dataset_util.bytes_feature(filename),
        'image/source_id': dataset_util.bytes_feature(filename),
        'image/encoded': dataset_util.bytes_feature(encoded_img),
        'image/format': dataset_util.bytes_feature(image_format),
        'image/object/bbox/xmin': dataset_util.float_list_feature(xmins),
        'image/object/bbox/xmax': dataset_util.float_list_feature(xmaxs),
        'image/object/bbox/ymin': dataset_util.float_list_feature(ymins),
        'image/object/bbox/ymax': dataset_util.float_list_feature(ymaxs),
        'image/object/class/text': dataset_util.bytes_list_feature(classes_text),
        'image/object/class/label': dataset_util.int64_list_feature(classes),
    }))
    return tf_example


def main(_):
    #print('In the name of Allah')
    writer = tf.python_io.TFRecordWriter(FLAGS.output_path)
    dataset_folders = FLAGS.images_folder #'G:\\Tensorflow_section\\dtset\\'
    #print('dataset_folders = '+dataset_folders)

    path = dataset_folders
    examples = pd.read_csv(FLAGS.csv_input)
    #print('examples: ',examples)   
    grouped = split(examples, 'filename')
    for group in grouped:
        tf_example = create_tf_example(group, path)
        writer.write(tf_example.SerializeToString())

    writer.close()
    output_path = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), FLAGS.output_path)
    print('Successfully created the TFRecords: {}'.format(output_path))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    tf.app.run()
```

Comment: How does your label map look like? How have you build the TFRecords?

Comment: @ITiger: I updated the question with the needed information.

Comment: Now that I see it, I guess I have done a mistake in the class_text_to_int() method! I should have written 2 instead of 0 and it seems 0 ignores that class altogether! Am I right?

Comment: `I am new to object detection and have no idea what is causing this.` - you have made a statement, and have failed to ask a question.  Stackoverflow is for questions, not statements.  With 4k + rep, you should be expected to know this by now.

Comment: @JK.: Yes, thats correct, my bad. updated the subject

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you have created the label map, just use it in your code. It is mentioned in the tutorial that the indices have to start from 1, because class 0 is treated as background. You can use the `label_map_util` module to create the labels.

```
from object_detection.utils import label_map_util
from object_detection.utils import dataset_util
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

LABEL_MAP_PATH = "/PATH/TO/LABEL_MAP.pbtxt"

def create_tf_example(directory, name):

    # Read Image file
    image_filename = "{}{}{}.jpg".format(directory, IMAGE_DIRECTORY, name)
    # Read XML Annotation
    xml_filename = os.path.join("{}{}{}.xml".format(directory, ANNOTATION_DIRECTORY, name))
    tree = ET.parse(xml_filename)
    root = tree.getroot()

    label_map_dict = label_map_util.get_label_map_dict(LABEL_MAP_PATH)

    classes = []
    classes_text = []
    for o in root.findall('object'):
        classes_text.append(o.find('name').text.encode('utf8'))
        classes.append(label_map_dict[o.find('name').text])

        example = tf.train.Example(features=tf.train.Features(feature={
        # Do all the other stuff
        'image/object/class/text': dataset_util.bytes_list_feature(classes_text),
        'image/object/class/label': dataset_util.int64_list_feature(classes),
        }))
    return examle
```

Answer (score -1):

I found the culprit!

here:

```
# TO-DO replace this with label map
def class_text_to_int(row_label):
    if row_label == 'class2':
        return 0
    if row_label == 'class1':
        return 1    
    else:
        None
```

Needs to be changed to

```
# TO-DO replace this with label map
def class_text_to_int(row_label):
    if row_label == 'class2':
        return 2
    if row_label == 'class1':
        return 1    
    else:
        None
```

to match

```
item{
 id: 1
 name: 'class1'
}
item{
 id: 2
 name: 'class2'
}
```